# Issue trying to print data from a web service with function file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, web-services, file-get-contents

When I use this code to print data from a local json file it works perfect.

```
 $json_string = 'data.json';
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
 $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($obj);
```

But I can´t make it works with a web service. I don't get any results..

```
 $json_string = 'http://ddddd.com/ws/ws_get_news.php?limit=10';
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
 $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($obj);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use double quotes: `file_get_contents("$json_string");`

Comment: Are you sure that your returned value is json?

Comment: Yes. Here is the web service url
http://dattabasic.com.ar/~masterli/admin/ws/ws_get_categorias.php

Comment: I can´t figure out where is the issue..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first characters of your generated JSON are the problem. Is it possible you are generating something with UTF8-BOM? You can solve this by strip the first characters. Try this:

```
 $json_string = 'http://dattabasic.com.ar/~masterli/admin/ws/ws_get_categorias.php';
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
 $jsondata = substr($jsondata,3);
 $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($obj);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It was driving me crazy! Now it works. Thank so much S. Pols.